# Rating bar Android alternative method for OnRatingBarChangeListener?

Tags: android, ratingbar, multipart-alternative

I am trying to find another alternative solution to check if the user has rated on the post.

The problem is that if I use OnRatingBarChangeListener another user might vote and change the rating which will fire the event.

I have tried onClickListener and OnTouchListener with no real success because they override the initial method and can't interact correctly with the Rating bar...

Any suggestions?

```
 if (ratingSimplePost.getDidRate() == true) {

         ratingViewHolder.starRating.setRating((float)ratingSimplePost.getAverageRating());
         ratingViewHolder.starRating.isIndicator();

        }else if(ratingSimplePost.getDidRate() == false){

            ratingSimplePost.setDidRate(true);
            ratingViewHolder.starRating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new SimpleRatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onRatingChanged(SimpleRatingBar simpleRatingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
    if (ratingViewHolder.starRating.getRating() == 0) {

    } else {
        ratingViewHolder.starRating.setRating(ratingViewHolder.starRating.getRating());

        double avgSum = ratingSimplePost.getAverageRating() * ratingSimplePost.getParticipantCount();
        double myRating = ratingViewHolder.starRating.getRating();

        myRating = (Math.round(myRating * 100));
        myRating = myRating / 100;


        double newRating = (avgSum + myRating) / (ratingSimplePost.getParticipantCount() + 1);
        newRating = (Math.round(newRating * 100));
        newRating = newRating / 100;


        ParseQuery<ParseObject> updateRating = ParseQuery.getQuery("Posts");
        updateRating.whereEqualTo("objectId", ratingSimplePost.getPostId());

        final double finalNewRating = newRating;
        final double finalMyRating = myRating;
        ratingSimplePost.setAverageRating(newRating);

        updateRating.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                        ParseObject object = objects.get(i);
                        object.put("AvgRating", finalNewRating);
                        ArrayList<Double> ratingValues = (ArrayList<Double>) object.get("Ratings");
                        ratingValues.add((double) finalMyRating);
                        object.put("Ratings", ratingValues);
                        ratingSimplePost.setNewRating(finalNewRating);
                        ArrayList<String> partList = (ArrayList<String>) object.get("Participants");
                        partList.add(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
                        object.put("Participants", partList);
                        object.saveInBackground();
                        ratingViewHolder.starRating.setRating((float) finalNewRating);
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the creator of the library you are using: [SimpleRatingBar](https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar).

You need to use the value of `boolean fromUser` in the `onRatingChanged` method. This has the same meaning as you would expect from the stock android RatingBar:

- True if the rating changed because of a user action (by touching the rating bar)
- False if the rating changed programatically (by calling setRating or using an animation)

So, in your code:

```
@Override
public void onRatingChanged(SimpleRatingBar simpleRatingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
    if (fromUser) {
        // user changed the rating by touching the rating bar

        double avgSum = ratingSimplePost.getAverageRating() * ratingSimplePost.getParticipantCount();
        double myRating = simpleRatingBar.getRating();

        myRating = (Math.round(myRating * 100));
        myRating = myRating / 100;


        double newRating = (avgSum + myRating) / (ratingSimplePost.getParticipantCount() + 1);
        newRating = (Math.round(newRating * 100));
        newRating = newRating / 100;


        ParseQuery<ParseObject> updateRating = ParseQuery.getQuery("Posts");
        updateRating.whereEqualTo("objectId", ratingSimplePost.getPostId());

        final double finalNewRating = newRating;
        final double finalMyRating = myRating;
        ratingSimplePost.setAverageRating(newRating);

        updateRating.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                        ParseObject object = objects.get(i);
                        object.put("AvgRating", finalNewRating);
                        ArrayList<Double> ratingValues = (ArrayList<Double>) object.get("Ratings");
                        ratingValues.add((double) finalMyRating);
                        object.put("Ratings", ratingValues);
                        ratingSimplePost.setNewRating(finalNewRating);
                        ArrayList<String> partList = (ArrayList<String>) object.get("Participants");
                        partList.add(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
                        object.put("Participants", partList);
                        object.saveInBackground();
                        ratingViewHolder.starRating.setRating((float) finalNewRating);
                    }

                }
            }
        });
      }
    }
   }
```

Also, keep in mind that there was a [bug](https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar/pull/9) which caused the library to always return false in the value of `fromUser`.
This will be corrected in version `0.1.1`, which I'll be releasing in a few minutes.

You can download this version either from `jcenter` or `Maven Central`. Just add to your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.+'
}
```

Comment: Thank you! you'are awesome!